# loading on splash screen with NSURL

Tags: ios

I have a NSURL which takes a huge time to load the url, I need to show a spinner, I am using the below code, but the spinner is the not the first thing which appears it shows a black screen first, I want the app to load the spinner first as it launches till the URL is loaded completed, Can anyone please help on this, It would be greatly appreciated.

```
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showLoading) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://strappcenter.net/strapp-projects/ohs/admin/jsonstring.php"];
    //NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://strappcenter.net/strapp-projects/ohs/admin/jsonstring.php"];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithContentsOfURL:URL
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];


    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(spinEnd) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the splash screen which is just like your first screen.
Then load the data from the internet.
Check out [this tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/).